# django query is select_related required for subsequent queries?

Tags: django, optimization

Given the following code:

```
    progresses = Progress.objects.filter(customer=request.user).select_related()
    if id is not None
        progress = progresses.get(pk=id)
    else:
        progress = progresses[0]
```

Do I need to add select_related() to the second query such as `progress = progresses.filter(pk=id).select_related()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your `progress` queryset object already has the foreign key relationships included in the underlying sql. It's creating a select query with joins. Filtering it further won't remove the joins.

There's an example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) of further processing a query that includes `select_related` (though not using `filter`).

Answer (score 0):

> The order of filter() and select_related() chaining isn’t important.
>   These querysets are equivalent:
>
> ```
> Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gt=timezone.now()).select_related('blog')
> Entry.objects.select_related('blog').filter(pub_date__gt=timezone.now())
> ```

From official Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/